# RxJS which operator to use for "onIdle"?

Tags: rxjs, reactive, redux-observable

My use case is as follows - i have a stream of operations for distinct elements and i want to only call "commit" on each object if they have been idle for a certain amount of time OR a different element is received.

I was trying around with groupBy and debounce, but did not get all the cases covered - e.g.

```
action.pipe(
  groupBy(item -> item.key),
  debounceTime(1000),
  mergeMap(item -> { 
           item.commit()})
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'idle'? How do check if an object has been idle?

Comment: idle as in "has not received an event for X millis"

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. So you want to call `commit` on an item emitted by `action` if no other item with the same key is emitted within X millis OR if another item with a different key is emitted?!

Comment: i want to call commit on the last received element if either an element with a different key arrives OR no event arrives for a given time.
A => A => B => A
should result in : A.commit() => B.commit() => <timeout> => A.commit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your goal:

Let's take the example of a situation where you have  **A => B => A** coming within less than the minimum idle time

**Option 1**: each type of element should have each own idle-state - the second emission of type A will be ignored
**Option 2**. since there is no consecutive sequence the second `A` will not be ignored

**OPTION 1 example:**

```js
action.pipe(
    groupBy(item => item.key),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(debounceTime(1000))),
    mergeMap(item => item.commit())
)
```

Optionally:

```js
const IDLE_TIME = XXXX;
action.pipe(
    groupBy(item => item.key),
    mergeMap(group => merge(
        group.pipe(first()),
        group.pipe(
            timeInterval(),
            filter(x => x.interval > IDLE_TIME),
            map(x => x.value)
        )
    )),
    mergeMap(item => item.commit())
)
```

**OPTION 2 example:**

```
 action.pipe(
     pairwise(),
     debounce(([previous, current]) => previous.key == current.key? timer(1000) : EMPTY),
     map(([pre, current]) => current),
     mergeMap(item => item.commit())
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assess the idle nature using [auditTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/audittime), [scan](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) and [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter)

```
action.pipe(
  //add the idle property to the item
  map(item => ({ ...item, idle: false})),
  //audit the stream each second
  auditTime(1000),
  //then use scan to with previous emission at audit time
  scan(
     (prev, curr) => {
       //then if the key remains the same then we have an idle state
       if (prev.key === curr.key) {
          //return changed object to indicate we have an idle state
          return Object.assign({}, curr, {idle: true});
       } else {
          //otherwise just return the non idle item
          return curr 
       }
    //seed with an object that cannot match the first emission key
    }, { key: null }
  ),
  //then filter out all emissions indicated as not idle
  filter(item => item.idle === true)
  //and commit
  mergeMap(item => item.commit())
)
```

Then you can use [distinctUntilKeyChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilkeychanged)  to achieve the second condition

```
action.pipe(
  distinctUntilKeyChanged('key'),
  mergeMap(item => item.commit())
)
```

I'm not familiar with `redux-observable` but you would typically `merge` these two observables and then commit at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure it's smart to use `auditTime` here

Comment: OK. Probably works best for any readers if you offer a reason?

Comment: also think about the case where you have 3 elements coming A --> B --> A, you code is only aware of the previous one.

Comment: Not with the `distinctUntilKeyChanged` emissions as well.

Comment: how  whould `distinctUntilKeyChanged` help you in the abovementioned case?

Comment: From my understanding of the problem, the OP wants to commit when a different element is received, which `distinctUntilKeyChanged` will do. In your example, A-->B-->A, all of these emissions will be committed. The idle observable will ignore each of them.